Why can't const be initialized in the static constructor? Why is const initialized exactly at compile time and how does this process happen?
const are initialized at compile time, the rest at runtime: static at class invocation time, other fields (not static) at instance creation time.
Question: why are const initialized at compile time? They are static, why can't they be assigned a value in the static constructor?
How does this happen in general?
if const are initialized, then it is necessary to refer to the class to understand that const exist inside it in principle and read their values, and therefore static should also have been worked out and initialized, as well as static constructor. But apparently this does not happen, so there is no reference to the class? Then how are the values of const read and why can't we access them without referring to the class?
For example: Console.WriteLine(MyClass.PI)?
Why can't we: Console.WriteLine(PI)? Because it is not known where PI is located. Then how can the compiler, not knowing where PI is and that it exists in principle, enter the value at the compilation stage without accessing the class?

The compiler may include the constant's value at compile time, instead of a reference to that const in that class

It might help to see constants as aliases for literals, which is what they effectively boil down to. They don't exist at runtime.

Because a const isn't really a variable that is initialized.
There's a variety of ways this could be done, but in C# under .Net the constants are being inserted into the code before it is converted to IL code (the assembly-like language that becomes the byte-code that .Net actually runs).
I used a tool called LINQPad8 to analyze a simple example of this situation:
class Program
{
    private const int VALUE = 10;
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value1 = 10;
        Console.WriteLine(value1);

        int value2 = VALUE;
        Console.WriteLine(value2);

        Console.WriteLine(VALUE);
    }
}

Before the code is even analyzed by ILSpy, the .Net tool which LINQPad is using to do the work, the constant has already been pre-processed out of the code, producing the following:
 int value1 = 10;
 Console.WriteLine (value1);
 int value2 = 10;
 Console.WriteLine (value2);
 Console.WriteLine (10);

and all of this becomes the following CLR IL code:
IL_0000 nop 
IL_0001 ldc.i4.s    0A  // 10
IL_0003 stloc.0    // value1
IL_0004 ldloc.0    // value1
IL_0005 call    Console.WriteLine (Int32)
IL_000A nop 
IL_000B ldc.i4.s    0A  // 10
IL_000D stloc.1    // value2
IL_000E ldloc.1    // value2
IL_000F call    Console.WriteLine (Int32)
IL_0014 nop 
IL_0015 ldc.i4.s    0A  // 10
IL_0017 call    Console.WriteLine (Int32)
IL_001C nop 
IL_001D ret 

Particularly in the last call where the constant VALUE is used directly as a parameter to the call to Console.WriteLine(Int32), no instructions for storing variables in memory are accessed, the calls to stloc and ldloc.
The integer 0x0A (10 in decimal) is pushed directly onto the stack as a 32-bit signed integer, which is how arguments are supplied to method calls.  The other two calls show how it looks when a variable is used and pushed onto the stack instead.

In short - because specification says so.
In a little bit more detail - constants (and local constant declarations), i.e. class members that represents a constant value, are initialized with constant expressions which (emphasis mine):

A constant expression is an expression that shall be fully evaluated at compile-time.

While static constructors are executed at runtime, they even can be not executed at all if program does not use the class with static ctor at all. For example the following ("on my machine"):
if (Random.Shared.Next(10) > 5)
{
    new TestStCtor();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("no static ctor");
}

class TestStCtor
{
    static TestStCtor()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("static ctor");
    }
}

When run multiple times prints or does not print "static ctor" (.NET 8, Windows).
Internally in CLR implementation of the C# constants are baked into the assembly/DLL at (again) compile time.
